# Hide form fields and realign other form fields accordingly in Swing UI

Tags: java, forms, swing

I am trying to design a UI in swing. I have multiple text fields in a panel. I have a `combobox`, upon the value of which I have to decide whether to show  particular fields or not. Check below images

When Yes is selected:

[image: On selecting Yes]

When No is selected:

[image: On selecting No]

I have multiple such fields that I would have to hide/show depending on certain values of other form fields. I know how to hide the component but I'm not sure how I would go about for realigning all the components.

What would be best way to do this in Swing? Is there any particular `layout` that I can use to achieve this?

Comment: [Card Layout](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html) maybe? Or remove-revalidate-repaint manually...

Comment: I hope you find my non-answer still helpful. Anyway: the one vote I got on your question pushed me on the bronze badge for the swing tag. So you won a ticket in the upvote lottery today.

Answer (score 2):

A non-answer here: I recommend to not do it like this.

You see, when you have the "same" panel in use, then I suggest to only disable/enable the elements you do not use. Meaning: for a user, it will be very confusing if elements appear/vanish.

It is a different story when your "panels" represent completely different "aspects"; but then I would still use *different* panel objects and exchange complete panels.

In other words: from a user experience point of view, you want to avoid too much "churn"; thus I suggest to make sure that your UI elements do stay put. As a user, you do **not** want that the UI elements "move" around because some entry field is going away, and therefore all other things are re-aligned.

If you still think you need such a feature; the comments give a good hint; as [CardLayout](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html):

> The CardLayout class manages two or more components (usually JPanel instances) that share the same display space. When using the CardLayout class, let the user choose between the components by using a combo box.